# ./configure command completed with warning, configure: WARNING: `missing' script is too old or missing

Tags: software-installation, make, zip, configure

After running command of ./configure

```
sams@sams-desktop:~/Desktop/softwedge-1.0.0$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
/home/sams/Desktop/softwedge-1.0.0/missing: line 3: $'\r': command not found
/home/sams/Desktop/softwedge-1.0.0/missing: line 5: $'\r': command not found
/home/sams/Desktop/softwedge-1.0.0/missing: line 9: $'\r': command not found
/home/sams/Desktop/softwedge-1.0.0/missing: line 14: $'\r': command not found
/home/sams/Desktop/softwedge-1.0.0/missing: line 19: $'\r': command not found
/home/sams/Desktop/softwedge-1.0.0/missing: line 24: $'\r': command not found
/home/sams/Desktop/softwedge-1.0.0/missing: line 29: $'\r': command not found
/home/sams/Desktop/softwedge-1.0.0/missing: line 47: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'home/sams/Desktop/softwedge-1.0.0/missing: line 47: `case "$1" in
configure: WARNING: `missing' script is too old or missing
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) none
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) none
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for LC_MESSAGES... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking for ngettext in libc... yes
checking for dgettext in libc... yes
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for dcgettext... yes
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
configure: error: cannot run /bin/bash ./config.sub
```

completing with the error and then when I try to make file showing error

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I am attaching hyperlink to the file which I am trying to install

[Open this link and download linux file at the end of this page](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-transfer-wedge-serial-data-into-the-keyboard-buffer-text-field)

Answer (score 0):

The `Linux Version of softwedge-1.0.0.zip` archive was apparently created with DOS-style CRLF line endings.

Start over, but this time use `unzip -a` to convert text files to the correct line endings. From `man unzip`:

> ```
>    -a     convert  text files.  Ordinarily all files are extracted exactly
>           as they are stored (as ``binary'' files).  The -a option  causes
>           files  identified by zip as text files (those with the `t' label
>           in zipinfo  listings,  rather  than  `b')  to  be  automatically
>           extracted  as such, converting line endings, end-of-file charac‐
>           ters and the character set itself as necessary.
> ```

Comment: Thanks this worked for ./configure command but now new error start occurring in make command.
main.c:27:34: fatal error: X11/extensions/XTest.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:298: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sams/softwedge-1.0.0/src'
Makefile:339: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sams/softwedge-1.0.0'
Makefile:232: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: @JayantNagle you will meed to ensure that the prerequisite development packages are installed on your system - for example, `X11/extensions/XTest.h` is provided by package `libxtst-dev`

Comment: yes I already installed libxtst-dev version, should I try other versions of libxtst